# Efficient redistribution of variable amounts

Tags: algorithm

I have this problem, where I am given `n` accounts, each of which store a percentage of the user's net worth. I have to move it from the current distribution to a user inputted distribution. To actually move the money, I call method `moveMoney(initialAcct, finalAcct, amnt)`, which I have to call the least number of times possible.

This looks like a classic algo problem, but nothing comes to mind on how to solve it. It seems a little like packing optimization, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Think about how you would solve it if you had to do it manually. Write down the steps you'd take. Write a program to do that.

Comment: I have this right now. First, check if any of the differences match up and call the method on those 2 values if they do. Second, if 1 doesn't work, try to match the largest subtraction and the largest addition and call the method on those 2 accounts. While I think it would happen upon the correct solution sometimes, I don't think this would either always minimize the calls to `moveMoney` nor do I think it would it be the most efficient way to implement this, yet I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: What's the maximum value of `n`?

Comment: I wasn't given a max value for `n`. Considering it's supposed to model user bank accounts, I assume it wouldn't go over something like 50, but there wasn't a stated max. Why does the max value matter though? Won't the most efficient algo be the same for any value of `n`?

Comment: This is equivalent to the optimal account balancing problem https://leetcode.com/problems/optimal-account-balancing/ which is NP-hard.

Comment: @Primusa I don't have a leetcode subscription. Would you be able to summarize the solution given?

Answer (score 0):

Consider when there are at least two ways of covering the missing amount in any one account but there's a benefit to choosing one over the other. For example,

```
index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
input:  0  1  6  3  4  0  0  0
target: 7  0  0  0  0  1  1  5
needed: 7 -1 -6 -3 -4  1  1  5
```

If we choose to cover amount 7 with (1, 6), we get

```
amount    index
     1 -> 0
     6 -> 0
     3 -> 5
     1 -> 6 // from index 5 to 6
     1 -> 7 // from index 5 to 7
     4 -> 7
```

6 transfers.

Whereas if we choose to cover amount 7 with (3, 4), we get

```
amount    index
     3 -> 0
     4 -> 0
     1 -> 5
     6 -> 6
     5 -> 7 // from index 6 to 7
```

5 transfers.

We can therefore see that for any one state, as we transition to the output, we may need to consider all possible exact covers. To the extent that different overages can lead to more states with potential exact covers, even the choices to create transitional overages are not guaranteed to be interchangeable.

One thing is certain, though: we want to move all overages to deficits.